# Fetching external api with cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I would like to fetch an email from an email provider and i know that  i could use `axios` or any other http client however since i added cypress can i just use `cy.request` to get data and store it or it should not be used for such purposes.

I can use axios as it shows here but why if i have cy.request

```
context('Verify email', () => {
    let inbox;
    before((done) => {
      // Configure timeout
      this.timeout(1000*60*5); // five minutes
      // Query the inbox
      axios.get(`${ENDPOINT}&tag=${TAG}&timestamp_from=${startTimestamp}&livequery=true`).then((response) => {
        inbox = response.data;
        done();
      }).catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the response in [a Cypress environment variable.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#Syntax)

```js
context('Verify email', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.request(`${ENDPOINT}}&tag=${TAG}&timestamp_from=${startTimestamp}&livequery=true`)
      .then((response) => {
        Cypress.env('inbox', response.body);
    });
  });

  it('test', () => {
    // reference the variable by Cypress.env('inbox')
  });
});
```

Comment: thank for comment, ye sure i could do that but my question is is it okey to do  those requests with cy.request or practice shows that is better to create custom http client class

Comment: Is there any other reason for `cy.request()` to exist? Why do you ask?

Comment: `cy.request()` is used to make network requests. I don't see a need to make a custom class unless you are doing something extremely unusual that requires it.